# Removing unusual characters, after decoding and encoding

Tags: python, string, list, utf-8, replace

So I've been looking into this for quite a bit, and so far I am taking a string and doing the following:

```
title = title.decode('windows-1252')
title = title.encode('utf-8','replace')
```

My string is as follows, although there can be other characters that are not removed.

```
Bus • Lorry • IT & Construction
```

Punctuation removed:

```
title = title.translate(string.punctuation)
```

This seems to become (after punctuation removal):

```
Bus â€¢ Lorry â€¢ IT Construction
```

Although now I get an issue where I split the string and try and join it back together. I split it to:

```
['Bus', '\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc2\xa2', 'Lorry', '\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc2\xa2', 'IT', 'Construction']
```

By:
    words = text.split(' ')

The try to rejoin once I've down some stemming per word:

```
text = ' '.join([stemmer.stem(word) for word in words])
```

And then, at this point I get an issue:

> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

But I'm confused as from reading sites, I need to encode and decode, which I think I've done correctly already....

Comment: You should process the text in `unicode` and later onlye before output, encoded again in `utf8`. Can you try that?

Comment: Also note that you aren't actually _removing punctuation_, you are just re-encoding it in utf8.

Comment: I am removing it: title = title.translate(string.punctuation) I just didn't put that part up

Comment: Where do those weird characters are coming anyways?

Comment: My database - has some parts which have strings with bullet points in

Comment: @PauloBu where do you suggest placing a encode part? and decode for win?

Comment: Can you post the whole code as a block?

Comment: I'm also very suspicious of those weird chars (`â€¢`) don't get where do they come from. They aren't present in your first string.

Comment: @FranklinPiat "Python:" should not be added to the title, because it is already in the tags. Please see: [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/229438)

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode after the data is input, use it as unicode and encode it only for output. An `UnicodeDecodeError` is raised when something tries to make an encoded string into an unicode object without knowing the original encoding.

In your case I'd try to do the splitting and running the stemmer *before* encoding to UTF-8. This would only be needed for output or (possibly) storage.

Comment: I tried this, where I did: decode, remove punct, stem, encode (in this order). I'm now having issues with the punctuation removal: title = title.translate(string.punctuation). Error shows it doesn't like the effect that I moved the encoding: translation table must be 256 characters long

Comment: from python docs: 
"string.punctuation

String of ASCII characters which are considered punctuation characters in the C locale." -- Neither your input nor your output are ASCII, so string.punctuation doesn't apply